# Accessing HDFS input split path in RDD methods

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

My HDFS file paths contains metadata that I'd like to access in Spark, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
sc.newAPIHadoopFile("hdfs://.../*"), ...)
  .map( rdd => /* access hdfs path here */ )
```

In Hadoop, I can access the path for the entire split through `FileSplit.getPath()`. Is there anything similar I can do in Spark, or will I have to append the path String to every single RDD element in an extended `NewHadoopRDD`, something I reckon could be fairly costly?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Closure that you provide to the map() method there is no metadata/execution context information available.

What you probably want is

```
mapPartitionsWithContext

Similar to mapPartitions, but allows accessing information about the processing state within the mapper
```

Then you can do something like

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext
def myfunc(tc: TaskContext, iter: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = {
  tc.addOnCompleteCallback(() => println(
    "Partition: "     + tc.partitionId +
    ", AttemptID: "   + tc.attemptId   +
    ", Interrupted: " + tc.interrupted))

  iter.toList.filter(_ % 2 == 0).iterator
}
a.mapPartitionsWithContext(myfunc).collect
```

**UPDATE** the previous solution does not provide the HDFS filename.  You may need to do something like this:

> - Create a custom InputFormat that extends the FileInputFormat
> - Create a custom RecordReader that for each line outputs the file associated with the InputSplit and then the actual value for each line
> - In your spark mapper you will parse out the first field that now caontains the hdfs filename, and the rest of the mapper remains the
>     same

Comment: It's close, but I can't seem to resolve a partitionId to the actual hdfs filename of the InputSplit.

Comment: @jkgeyti  I see your point.  Unless you write a custom Partitioner that has knowledge of the input filenames then there will NOT be any relation between partitionID and hdfs filename.  I have updated my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Your update is exactly what I'm doing now :) It just annoys me that I have to accept the overhead of adding the path as part of every single RDD element, when the functionality is so close to being there - what I'm looking for is something along the lines of a `HadoopRDD.mapPartitionsWithHadoopContext`-like method.